# how to copy only the columns in a DataTable to another DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to copy only the columns in a DataTable to another DataTable?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`DataTable.Clone()` should do the trick.

```
DataTable newTable = originalTable.Clone();
```

Comment: First DataTable 238 columns and Second Datatable  has 107 columns using  DataTable newTable = originalTable.Clone(); then All columns copy to direct  Second Table

Answer (score 37):

If only the columns are required then `DataTable.Clone()` can be used. With `Clone` function only the schema will be copied. But `DataTable.Copy()` copies both the structure and data

E.g.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column Name");
dt.Rows.Add("Column Data");
DataTable dt1 = dt.Clone();
DataTable dt2 = dt.Copy();
```

`dt1` will have only the one column but `dt2` will have one column with one row.

Answer (score 3):

`Datatable.Clone` is slow for large tables. I'm currently using this:

```
Dim target As DataTable = 
    New DataView(source, "1=2", Nothing, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    .ToTable()
```

Note that this only copies the structure of source table, not the data.

Comment: OP asked for C# solution. This is VB

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the `DataTable` to another `DataTable` of different `Schema Structure` then you can do this:

- Firstly Clone the first `DataType` so that you can only get the structure.
- Then alter the newly created structure as per your need and then copy the data to newly created `DataTable`
  .

So:

```
Dim dt1 As New DataTable
dt1 = dtExcelData.Clone()
dt1.Columns(17).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
dt1.Columns(26).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
dt1.Columns(30).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
dt1.Columns(35).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
dt1.Columns(38).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
dt1 = dtprevious.Copy()
```

Hence you get the same `DataTable` but revised structure

Answer (score 1):

If you want the structure of a particular data table(dataTable1) with column headers (without data) into another data table(dataTable2), you can follow the below code:

```
        DataTable dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone();
        dataTable2.Clear();
```

Now you can fill dataTable2 according to your condition. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable.Clone()` method works great when you want to create a completely new DataTable, but there might be cases where you would want to add the schema columns from one DataTable to another *existing* DataTable.

For example, if you've derived a new subclass from DataTable, and want to import schema information into it, you couldn't use Clone().

E.g.:

```
public class CoolNewTable : DataTable {
   public void FillFromReader(DbDataReader reader) {
       // We want to get the schema information (i.e. columns) from the 
       // DbDataReader and 
       // import it into *this* DataTable, NOT a new one.
       DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable(); 
       //GetSchemaTable() returns a DataTable with the columns we want.

       ImportSchema(this, schema); // <--- how do we do this?
   }
}
```

The answer is just to create new DataColumns in the existing DataTable using the schema table's columns as templates.

I.e. the code for ImportSchema would be something like this:

```
void ImportSchema(DataTable dest, DataTable source) {
    foreach(var c in source.Columns)
        dest.Columns.Add(c);
}
```

or, if you're using Linq:

```
void ImportSchema(DataTable dest, DataTable source) {
    var cols = source.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
    dest.Columns.AddRange(cols);
}
```

This was just one example of a situation where you might want to copy schema/columns from one DataTable into another one without using Clone() to create a completely new DataTable. I'm sure I've come across several others as well.

Comment: if I try to do a loop like your suggested iteration shown above in 'ImportSchema' - I get an error saying the column already belongs to another DataTable. In other words, you can't loop an existing DataTable's column collection and assign those specific instances over to a different DataTable instance.

Comment: I think this might be the way to write out ImportSchema
            Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
            srcDataTable.WriteXmlSchema(ms)
            ms.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
            destDataTable.ReadXmlSchema(ms)

Comment: The last two examples will fail with the error message: System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'Name' already belongs to another DataTable.'

Comment: this answer need to be delete.